# SwiftUI Edit Item From List Using CoreData

Tags: listview, core-data, swiftui

I am working on a list app and would like the ability to edit the list item details.  I am using CoreData for the data model.  Right now I am stuck on how to pass the data item from the `DetailView` to the `EditItemView`. I updated to the code to the current state I am at.  I am currently getting an error in the `DetailView` taged to the `DetailView(myItem: item)` line the preview. Am I setting the `@State` correctly for `name` and passing the `@Binding` correctly?  I think my error lies in the way I am passing the name in `EditItemView(name: self.$name)` to the edit view.  Thoughts?

Detail View:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @ObservedObject var myItem: Item

    @State private var name: String
    @State private var showingEditScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(self.myItem.name ?? "Unknown Item")
                Text(self.myItem.attribute ?? "Unknown attribute")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(myItem.name ?? "Unknown Item"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.showingEditScreen.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
            }
        )
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingEditScreen) {
            EditItemView(name: self.$name).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

    static var previews: some View {
        let item = Item(context: moc)
        item.name = "Test item"
        item.attribute = "Test attribute"

        return NavigationView {
            DetailView(myItem: item)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit Item View:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Binding var name: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter Item Name", text: self.$name)
    }
}

struct EditItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditItemView(name: .constant("ItemX"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code in the post.  Still getting errors.

Comment: The build error I am getting is:  Cannot invoke initializer for type 'DetailView' with an argument list of type '(myItem: Item)'

Comment: It will build if I comment out ```@State private var name: String``` and ```.sheet(isPresented: $showingEditScreen) {EditItemView(name: self.$name).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)}``` in the Detail View.  I really can't figure out what is the correct syntax to pass the data to the next view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the `Item` or a `NSManagedObject` is an ObservableObject.

so you can directly use an item in a View:

```
 struct EditItemView: View  {

     @ObservedObject var myItem : Item

      var body: some View {
       ...}

 }
```

Comment: Missed that.  Added but still does not allow me to build and send the item to the edit screen.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were talking about in EditItemView.  I got it now.  Once I setup the new @ObservedObject in the EditItemView and used that name in the DetailView to pass the data, it worked great.  Thanks so much for the help!